Target Class [config] Does Not Exist When Running Unit Tests After Upgrading Laravel from 6 to 11
I recently upgraded my Laravel application from version 6 to 11, and after upgrading all the libraries, I'm encountering an issue when running unit tests. Specifically, the error states that the config class is not found:
Message: Target class [config] does not exist.

Location: C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:944

However, when I use tinker, I can successfully retrieve values from the configuration files. The issue only occurs when running the PHPUnit tests.
Here is the trace of the error:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(944): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(819): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(755): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(124): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(279): app('config')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\service-lar\app\Services\PriceService.php(23): config('configfile.currency...')

Actions I have already tried:

Clear and rebuild caches:

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan optimize:clear



Ensure proper bootstrap of Laravel in tests: I verified that the phpunit.xml file is correctly configured and the TestCase is properly set up.

Verify the configfile config file: I checked the configfile config file, and it contains valid values.

Check for missing service providers: I verified that the service providers in config/app.php are correctly listed.

Resolve dependencies properly in tests: In the tests, I ensured that dependencies are resolved using app() or resolve() when necessary.


The issue:
Even though config values are accessible in tinker, the tests fail to access them. The error occurs when the test tries to resolve the PriceService service, which calls the config function to retrieve configuration values.
Can anyone provide insights into why this is happening and how I can resolve it?
Additional Information:

Laravel version: 11

PHPUnit version: [Insert PHPUnit version here]

PHP version: [Insert PHP version here]


I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions!

Where is exactly that service being called? Is it inside the test method, or setUp or where?

@matiaslauriti It is being called inside the test method.

Are you sure you correctly migrated the TestCase file to the current version?

Yes, I have checked that with current version compatibility.
There were certain libraries which were there which I had removed and certain code were there, so I updated them.
